# read /write file in c++, choose option

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to write a code for signup / login  while being able to write and read from the file. So far I am able to write in the file and asked for the users input and displayed in the file (signup).
My problem is now,

1. How do I do the login part, in which when the user chooses login, they are able to choose what username they want based on a selection of usernames and the input they have made while choosing the first option?
2. How can this information be read and displayed in the file?

---

**Expected output for user login**
Choose you username:
0:mike
1:Linda
2:Martha

**Expected input from the user**
your choice: "Key in choice"

---

So far the code displayed works, but I am not sure what to do for my next step.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
    int option;
    int age,height;
    string name;
    string database;
    ofstream file_out;
    ifstream file_in;
  
     cout << " For sign up type 1" <<endl;
     cout << " For log in type 2" <<endl;
     cin >> option;

if ( option == 1 ) {
    file_out.open("database.txt");
    cout << "Input name:  \n";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Input age:  \n";
    cin >> age;
    cout << " Input height:  \n";
    cin >> height;
    
    
    //write file
    file_out << name << endl;
    file_out << age << endl;
    file_out << height << endl;

    file_out.close();
    
} else if (option == 2) {
//read file
file_in.open("database.txt");
cout << "choose your username: " << endl;
//  input line of code
while ( getline(file_in, database));
//input line of code
     cout << database << endl;
```

Comment: try GeeksforGeeks and programiz.com there are lot of stuff regrading your program

Comment: Adding expected input and output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Print all the usernames, but before printing out check if they are numbers with help of the `stof` function, if they are numbers we don't have to do anything, but if it is a string it will throw an exception, so in the `catch` block we print it and store it into `dictionary`/`map` for easy retrieval.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(void) {

  std::fstream file;
  file.open("secret.txt", std::ios::in);
  std::map<int, std::string> map;

  std::string username;

  int count = 1;
  while (!file.eof()) {
    file >> username;
    try {
      std::stof(username);
    } catch (...) {
      std::cout << count << ". " << username << "\n";
      map.insert(std::make_pair(count, username));
      count++;
    }   
  }
  int choice;
  std::cout << "Choose your username: ";
  std::cin >> choice;

  username = map.at(choice);

  std::cout << "Your username is set to " << username;

  return 0;
}
```